# Artifactory to Artifactory remote repos

Tags: artifactory, remote-repository

i have 2 Artifactory server and have configured ubuntu repos.
One off the artifactorys goes to internet to ubuntu and the other
artifactory connects to the artifactory with internet access.

I have the following problem. From my local artifactory i get always the error 404.
I cant fetch the metafile (Packages) from the ubuntu repo.

But if i reconfigure my remote repo and set --> store artifacts locally all seems fine.

I want store the artifacts locally. My local artifactory should ask the artifactory with internet access and should get all files from the remote artifactory.

Have anyone a idea how to solve my problem?

best regards

Comment: Just to make sure - did you create the remote repositories as Debian remote repositories (see [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Debian+Repositories#DebianRepositories-RemoteRepositories))?
It is important so that Artifactory can manage the index correctly.

Comment: Yes remote repo Typ is debian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to set up a smart remote repository with Artifactory. Refer to this [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Smart+Remote+Repositories) and set up the smart remote repository, basically, you should be adding the URL in your local Artifactory's remote repository as http://ARTIFACTORY_URL/ubuntu-remote/ and make sure the "store artifacts locally"is checked so that this remote repository can able to index the artifacts.

Comment: Thanks for your help.